# Why can't I pass this function? C++

Tags: c++

I have a function which takes in a pointer to a function:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyObj> MyObj::Create(const std::function<std::shared_ptr<MyInterface>()>& my_func);
```

Then I have a function such as:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyInterface> MyQualifier::GetInterfaceInstance() {
    return my_interface_instance;
}
```

But when I try:

```
my_obj = MyObj::Create(&MyQualitifer::GetInterfaceInstance);
```

I get an error:

```
Reference to type const std::function<std::shared_ptr<MyInterface> ()>' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'std::shared_ptr<MyInterface> (ParentQualifier::MyQualifier::*)()'
```

Why is this?

For reference, I have a similar function defined as:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyInterface> CreateMyInterface();
```

And the follow code works as expected:

```
my_obj = MyObj::Create(&CreateMyInterface);
```

Comment: `MyQualifier::GetInterfaceInstance` is effectively a function taking one parameter - `MyQualifier*` (represented in the function body by `this` keyword). It needs an instance of `MyQualifier` to be called on. That's why it cannot be converted to `std::function<Something()>` - the latter can be called with no arguments.

Comment: An [mcve] for this question [could look like this](https://ideone.com/Ho41NX).

Comment: Is GetInterfaceInstance a static function on the class or a member function on an instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by [@IgorTandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik), the issue seems to be with the non static member function of the class.

In case of non-static member function, `this` is added implicitly by the compiler.

That's why the compiler complains. Because the function doesn't match with the type expected in `std::shared_ptr<MyObj> MyObj::Create(const std::function<std::shared_ptr<MyInterface>()>& my_func);`.

Solution:

Option 1) Make it static. Like this:

```
class MyQualifier {
    ...
    public:
    static std::shared_ptr<MyInterface> MyQualifier::GetInterfaceInstance() {
        return my_interface_instance;
    }
}
...
auto my_obj = MyObj::Create(&MyQualitifer::GetInterfaceInstance); // now, this should work
```

Please note that in this case, `my_interface_instance` should be a static data member.

Option 2) Create an object of `MyQualifier` and use lambda.

```
int main() {
    auto my_obj = MyObj::Create([]() {
        auto myQualifierInstance = MyQualifier{};
        return myQualifierInstance->GetInterfaceInstance();
    });
}
```